# Trying to push items in an array to store in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, local-storage

just have a question about how to push onto an array to ultimately store in the localstorage. I have the below code:

```
  const handleSelectLayouts = (layout) => {
    const layoutsArray = [];
    layoutsArray.includes(layout)
        ? layoutsArray.filter((str) => str !== layout)
        : layoutsArray.push(layout);
    localStorage.setItem('layouts', JSON.stringify([...layoutsArray]));
    console.log(layoutsArray)
  }
```

I see it in localstorage, however, it only has one item at a time. In the code, I am trying to push onto an array. Not just have whatever is the most recent item inside the array alone. Anyone see anything odd here?

Comment: `layoutsArray` is an empty array. In other words, is not being read from local storage. For example, try `layoutsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layouts'))`

Comment: @EricFortis Thanks for your response. But I am trying to push to localstorage rather than grab it. Is it the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the previously stored layoutsArray from the local storage

```
 const handleSelectLayouts = (layout) => {
      let layoutsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layouts')) || [];
      if (layoutsArray.includes(layout)) {
        layoutsArray = layoutsArray.filter((str) => str !== layout);
      } else {
        layoutsArray.push(layout);
      }
      localStorage.setItem('layouts', JSON.stringify(layoutsArray));
      console.log(layoutsArray)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a new layoutsArray every time the function is called

```js
const layoutsArray = [];
```

If you want to add to the array which is already in localStorage then try this

```js
const layoutsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layouts')) || [];
```